# Retain print spool until printer available?

Tags: macos, printing, document-management

I'd like to be able to add, by script and by hand, files on dropbox to the print queue and for these to be retained there until I'm at a specific printer with my Macbook Pro.

As it is now, I add docs to be printed when the printer isn't available and after a while these are removed before the printer becomes available.

Is there a setting in OS X I can use to retain the files of the print spool until the printer in question is available?

Alternatively, is there a simple print spool application that can handle this task? I've looked in the App Store and on macupdate.com and googled and found very little.

Any suggestions how to solve this issue in OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all macs using cups for printing, you can manage it with a web interface. To enable it, you have to type:

```
cupsctl WebInterface=yes
```

Then you should be able to check print server configuration, printers and queues from:

```
http://127.0.0.1:631/
```

If you enter in this website, under `Administration → Server`, click on `Advance` and yo must see something like the following image:

[image]

As you can see, you will be able to modify the `Retain Documents` parameter, that is the amount of time a Document stay on the printer queue.

Comment: I was hoping for something like this existed. These settings should be available at the printer settings though. Sometimes I feel Apple hides away settings for no good reasons, that everyday users need. I'll try this out now.